# ASP.Net-Core option validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have written an extension method to `IServiceCollection` which takes an option delegate. My problem here is that I have to validate the configured options first (e.g. filter out `null` values) since it's unsafe to proceed and instantiate a service that relies on these options.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static void AddServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<ServiceOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        // Configure service
        services.AddSingleton<IAbstraction, Implementation>();

        // Validate options here...

        // Configure options
        services.Configure(configureOptions);
    }
}
```

How can I validate here that the options are correctly specified without calling the delegate `configureOptions`? I don't want to rely on default values from `ServiceOptions` since I want to make some settings mandatory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## ASP.NET Core 2.2+

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-validation)

There is a validation method on the [`OptionsBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsbuilder-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0). The validation will occur on the first use of the `IOptions<T>.Value` property. It will throw an `OptionsValidationException` if not valid. Eager validation is tracked [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/459).

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static void AddServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<ServiceOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        // Configure service
        services.AddSingleton<IAbstraction, Implementation>();

        // Configure and validate options
        services.AddOptions<ServiceOptions>()
            .Configure(configureOptions)
            .Validate(options => {
                // Take the fully configured options and return validity...
                return options.Option1 != null;
            });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, `.ValidateDataAnnotations()` is available too so the data annotation attributes are respected.

## ASP.NET Core 2.0+

From ASP.NET Core 2.0 onwards, `PostConfigure` is a good fit. This function takes a configuration delegate too but is executed last, so everything is already configured.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static void AddServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<ServiceOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        // Configure service
        services.AddSingleton<IAbstraction, Implementation>();

        // Configure and validate options
        services.Configure(configureOptions);
        services.PostConfigure<ServiceOptions>(options => {
            // Take the fully configured options and run validation checks...
            if (options.Option1 == null) {
                throw new Exception("Option1 has to be specified");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `PostConfigure` and `PostConfigureAll`?

Comment: With names options, you can have multiple instances of e.g. `ServiceOptions`, all with different values. The delegate you pass to `PostConfigureAll` will run for all instances. More information [here](http://www.jiodev.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/Configuration/options#named-options-support-with-iconfigurenamedoptions)

Comment: @lonix `PostConfigure` only configures instances that match the name you passed in (or the default name if you call the overload that does not take a string). `PostConfigureAll` will configure all options that match the type, not caring about the name of the options object.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain And if the source is a file (e.g. `appsettings.json`) which is reloaded on change, will the postconfig run again? Docs don't guarantee it, so is there some "proper" way to do that?